# Bootstrap Tooltips showing like Regular HTML Tooltips

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I've tried everything, popups show great, but tooltips just show like a regular HTML tooltip. 
[image]

This is what I have in my code

HTML

```
    <th rel="tooltip" title="Number of calls made to our API">Api Call</th>
```

Javascript

```
  //Tooltips
      $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip({
      'selector': '[rel=tooltip]',
      'placement': 'top'
      });
```

and As far as i can tell im importing the bootstrap css and js good since modals, and popovers work great all through the site.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The double definition of selector seems to be throwing off Bootstrap's tooltip. If you remove the `'selector': '[rel=tooltip]',` from the object you pass to `.tooltip()` that should fix it.

Your markup would then look like:

```
<th rel="tooltip" title="Number of calls made to our API">Api Call</th>
```

And your JavaScript would look like:

```
//Tooltips
$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip({
  'placement': 'top'
});
```

Since you are already selecting elements with the `rel` attribute set to "tooltip" you don't need to specify the selector in the object you are passing in.

For a working, unstyled, demo [check out this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonmerino/Jzeja/)

Also, to specify further, adding in the selector like you had before is useful when defining tooltips like this:

```
$(document).tooltip({
    'selector': '[rel=tooltip]',
    'placement': 'bottom'
});
```

Comment: Thank you, you were right.  it was throwing the bootstrap off.

Comment: @AdrianMojica glad to be of assistance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your  tag should be like this:

```
<th rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Number of calls made to our API">Api Call</th>
```

You forgot to add the `data-toggle="tooltip"`part.

Comment: I added it, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the tooltip initialization is done when the document is ready like this..

```
$(function () {
   $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip({placement:'top'});
});
```

or..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip({placement:'top'});
});
```